# jQuery Toggle on mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have the following jQuery:

```
$('#account-menu').hide();

$("#account-link").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#account-menu").toggle();
     $("#account-link").toggleClass("selected");
});
```

What I want to do is check if the user clicks anywhere else onscreen **WHILST THE ACCOUNT MENU IS SHOWN** BUT not within the account menu itself, and if so then hide the menu. Can anyone help?

Thanks

EDIT:
I had a go at doing this myself like so:

```
$('#account-menu').hide();

    $("#account-link").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#account-menu").toggle('fast');
        $("#account-link").toggleClass("selected");
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        var $targ = $(e.target);

        // if we are the link or the box, exit early
        if ($targ.is('#account-link') || $targ.is('#account-menu')) return;
        // if we have a parent who is either, also exit early
        if ($targ.closest('#account-link, #account-menu').length) return;

        // hide the box, unselect the link
        $("#account-link").removeClass("selected");
        $("#account-menu").hide('fast');
    });
```

But wanted to see if there was a nicer and much smaller (code-wise) way of doing it.

Comment: Please see my `UPDATE #2` below. Working on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this...

```
$('#account-menu').hide();

$('body').click(function(){
    $("#account-menu:visible').toggle();
    $("#account-link").removeClass("selected");
});

$("#account-link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#account-menu:not:visible").toggle();
    $("#account-link").addClass("selected");
});
```

**UPDATE**

So this won't fully work, since the body click triggers when you click the link too. This is a step in the right direction though. G/L

**UPDATE #2**

I finally got this working over on JSFiddle.net, using the comments from `Joseph Le Brech` (+1). [Check out the live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/edGrd/3/). I could not get the `$('body')` selector working on there, so I am simulating the body with a div called `bodyDiv`. It's all commented and working 100%. Happy Coding.

Comment: add a class when the buttons are hovered, then in body test to see which button is currently hovered.

Answer (score 1):

[Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-div-when-click-outside-it)